# Making a pandas function asynchronous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-asyncio

Consider the following snippet.

```
import asyncio

import pandas as pd


# @asyncio.coroutine
async def read(some_id):
    '''
    '''
    # await ?, yield ?, yield from ?
    return pd.read_sql_query(f'''SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id={some_id}''',
                                con) # how do I make this line awaitable.
```

I want to be able to make that function awaitable so that I can pass ids in an array and start queries simultaneously because it takes lots of time to read the table, something like.

```
async def main():
    '''
    '''
    alltasks = []
    for some_id in [3, 2, 5]:
        task = asyncio.create_task(read(some_id))
        alltasks.append(task)
    res = await asyncio.gather(*alltasks)
```

Right now this executes the queries synchronously because my function is not truly asynchronous, so how do I make it truly asynchronous.
I know I can use asycio.sleep(0) but that will not execute the query, how can I achieve this without use of concurrent.future.ThreadPoolExecutor like in other answers.

Appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: What is your bottleneck? Is it waiting on your database queries or is it something related to processing the results?

Comment: Querying the db, It is a very big table with lots of rows.

Comment: You might be able to use an asyncio-aware database driver. You’d have to fetch the data yourself and hand the result to Pandas rather than letting it do the query for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn any regular function into an awaitable coroutine via [`asyncio.to_thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread):

```py
def read(some_id): # note: no await!
    return pd.read_sql_query(...)

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.to_thread(read, some_id) for some_id in [3, 2, 5]]
    res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```